# how to fetch the list of the function which are in apex class through soql query

Tags: apex, soql

i want the list of the function name with argument with a particular class.
suppose i have global class A{}. inside this class I have 4 or 5 functions like funcA(int),funcB(string), etc.. 
i want a list of the all this functions with argument.

Comment: i guess this is not possible because classes are not stored in the database. Hence it is not possible to query the data through soql. Maybe it is possible through the meta data api but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the exact requirement but you can achieve it by Tooling API object `SymbolTable`.

Using this you can get name of method, modifier, parameters etc.

Here is the description of [SymbolTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm)

**How to get started with Tooling API?**
You can follow this link: [Introducing Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My exact requirement is to get the name and parameters of the class.
`global Class A{
       global void funcA(params){.....}
       global void funcB(param){.....}
       global void funcC(par1, par2){.....}`
it should return me list 
funA(params), funcB(params),funcC(par1,par2)